# NameError: name 'Klout' is not defined

Tags: python, klout

I am facing a weird error in python klout API. I have installed klout module with pip install. 
I have created a api key and I use the following code:

```
from klout import *
 k = Klout('key')
```

My code was running normally until before 5 minutes whereI received:

```
 k = Klout('key')
 NameError: name 'Klout' is not defined
```

Any idea about this error? Is there any call limit per hour??

Comment: You probably added a file `klout.py` in your path somewhere, masking the library you actually *wanted* to import. What does `import klout; print(klout.__file__)` tell you you imported?

Comment: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\klout\__init__.pyc

Comment: In your failing script? Or in a separate new python interpreter? The `sys.path` module search path includes the current working directory, and if you *changed* that then you won't see the same problem.

Comment: I create a script just for print klout.__file__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably added a file `klout.py` in your path somewhere, masking the library you actually *wanted* to import.

You can diagnose what file that is by printing the `__file__` attribute on the Cuckoo module:

```
import klout
print(klout.__file__)
```

Rename that file; you don't want to mask your library.

Comment: Jesus, indeed, I create a file klout.py wuithout even noticed. You are good!!